# implementing Js widget: Relying on $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] variable to check on the host domain is safe?

Tags: javascript, php, widget, cross-domain

I'm implementing a Js widget , the widget with source code is on domain1.com
the host of the widget(viewer) is on domain2.com

On domain1.com I'm using PHP as server scripting language.

What I need is to check if the widget hosting domain is allowed to get an answer from domain1.com serving the widget service.

I was thinking to perform something like this:

on domain2.com:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="widget-container"></div>        
    </body>
    <script src="http://domain1.com/widget/viewer.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

on domain1.com:

```
<?php 
    if(in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $allowedDomains)){
       /* echo all widget goodness*/
    }else{
        die('you\'ve not permission to get this service');
    }
?>
```

Is it reliable to check on `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable to grant  the host domain to access my widget?

Comment: what do you mean with safe?
the referer could be forged, but depending the security level you want it will be acceptable or not.

Comment: With safe I mean, if there's any chance that the referer could be empty  or changed. Because only I grant access to my widget data to a certain domainname.com with widget hosting page, if there's the chance, mentioned above, it won't get any data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, its not safe, the referer can be tampered at will.

see [referer-control](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hnkcfpcejkafcihlgbojoidoihckciin)

in fact, anything in the request can be forged.

you should look something else to secure your widget, like https+sessions.